# Big Query For-In not picking up table paths from a look-up table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a look-up table containing a list of fully qualified table paths in a Big Query table called **all_tables**. For example

```
|table_list|
|----------|
|project_name.dataset_name1.table_1|
|project_name.dataset_name2.table_1|
|project_name.dataset_name3.table_1|
|project_name.dataset_name4.table_1|
|project_name.dataset_name5.table_1|
```

I am trying to iterate through these tables to pull out elements I need for another procedure using the [for-in](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#for-in) syntax in Big Query. This is a simplified version of the query I am using

````
```
FOR table IN (select * from my_project.my_dataset.all_tables)
DO
select * from table;
END FOR;
```
````

This isn't working. It picks up the list of tables correctly, but when it substitutes the dataset name in the line 3 select statement, it says

```
**Invalid value: Table "table" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table)**
```

I know what the error is, but I am not sure how to make it 'see' the value of table as a table path.

All paths are correct, and I am doing it this way as I am querying multiple tables across multiple datasets for a table creation query.

Comment: what is your real use case?! obviously looping through tables with `select *` makes no sense. - I think you are in the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) situation

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I'm actually trying to solve this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73154281/how-to-concatenate-lots-of-tables-into-one-look-up-table-automatically-in-bigque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should a dynamic sql to refer the table name as a variable, so consider below query:

```sql
FOR table IN (select * from my_project.my_dataset.all_tables)
DO
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  SELECT * FROM %s;
""", table.table_list);
END FOR;
```